# Загрузочная флешка на линукс

Tags: linux, uefi

У меня стоит OS Garuda Linux. Я решил перейти на Linux Manjaro и сделал загрузочную флешку при помощи утилиты DD. Проблема заключается в том, что UEFI не видит флешку. Можно ли запустить ее через консоль?

Comment: Образ был iso или img?

Comment: Если образ iso, то записывать на флешку утилитой `dd` бесполезно. Либо возможно bios  и определит флешку как CD-rom.  Но UEFI вряд ли загрузится.

Comment: Образ ISO. Как правильно создать загрузочную флешку? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @DiD а почему `iso` бесполезно записывать `dd`? Всю жизнь так делал.

Comment: @user207200 Писать UDF на флешку может и норм, но я обычно UEFI загружаю с FAT32. Bios без проблем загрузит с флешки и с UDF.

Comment: Какой образ? Ссылку в студию.

Comment: старческое ворчание в сторону: и чего только люди не придумают, чтобы не пользоваться программой cp. etcher-ы какие-то, dd за каким-то лешим… // религия не позволяет, что ли? // ответ-то банальный: если образ подготовлен не для загрузки с помощью uefi, а в настройках uefi это не разрешено, то ничего тут не поделаешь: надо пересобирать образ.

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем минусовать правильные ответы. Из за любви к команде cp? Можно записать cp. Кстати можно записать и cat и tee. От этого факта способ с использованием eatcher, rufus, dd или любой другой не становится не правильным.  Кстати образ manjaro грузится в обоих BIOS и UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Можно писать флешку утилитой [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

Установить вроде можно `pacman -S etcher`.

Либо найти в гуях `pamac`.

[image: Окно Etcher в работе]

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Записывать dd можно и должна грузиться.
В общем случае команда из учётной записи root, или запускать через sudo:

```
dd bs=4M if=/path/to/manjaro.iso of=/dev/sd[drive letter] status=progress oflag=sync
```

Проверьте, что бы в настройках bios:

- UEFI в ON
- Secure boot обязательно OFF

а вообще не видит флэшку как таковую? Другую даже если без загрузчика BIOS в принципе видит?

Comment: Такой способ сработает только если у вас изначально iso образ «гибридный», то есть с двумя загрузчиками, подходящими и для CD и для HDD/flash

Comment: iso archlinux "гибридный"